# Split string into array with bash/awk

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a string of the form:

```
  "\nFIRST_ITEM\nSECOND_ITEM\nTHIRD_ITEM\n"
```

When I try to use awk to split it into an array like so,

```
  echo "\nFIRST_ITEM\nSECOND_ITEM\nTHIRD_ITEM\n" | awk '{split($0,a,"\n")}'
```

The whole string just gets stored as is into a[1]. Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `bash`:

```
a="\nFIRST_ITEM\nSECOND_ITEM\nTHIRD_ITEM\n"
a=( ${a//\\n/ } )
```

It replaces each `\n` with a space.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question but this MAY be what you're looking for:

```
$ echo "\nFIRST_ITEM\nSECOND_ITEM\nTHIRD_ITEM\n" |
    awk '{split($0,a,/\\n/); for (i=1;i in a;i++) print i, "<" a[i] ">"}'
1 <>
2 <FIRST_ITEM>
3 <SECOND_ITEM>
4 <THIRD_ITEM>
5 <>
```

assuming your echo outputs `\n` as the string `\n` and not a newline character.